# Determining format of SSL certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https

I've been given access to some SSL certificates to install in a Rails app. However, I can't figure out what format they are, and how to get my app to use them. I originally set the server up to use some self-signed certificates. Here's the except from `script/rails`:

```
module Rails
    class Server < ::Rack::Server
        def default_options
            super.merge({
                :Port => 3000,
                :environment => (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development").dup,
                :daemonize => false,
                :debugger => false,
                :pid => File.expand_path("tmp/pids/server.pid"),
                :config => File.expand_path("config.ru"),
                :SSLEnable => true,
                :SSLVerifyClient => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
                :SSLPrivateKey => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(
                       File.open("server.key").read),
                        # $private_key),
                :SSLCertificate => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(
                       File.open("server.crt").read),
                :SSLCertName => [["CN", WEBrick::Utils::getservername]]
            })
        end
    end
end
```

I have been given three files. One is named `server.key`, and it's just a normal RSA private key. That one's fine.

The next is named `server_cert.cer`. It's a 32 line file, which starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`. The actual base64 code in it has 1864 characters in it. I'm confused by this file: it looks like an SSL certificate, but my self-signed SSL certificate was only 24 lines long.

I also have a file called `server_interim.cer`. It has three certificates concatenated together, all of which are different from `server_cert.cer`.

If I just blindly tell Rails to load `server_cert.cer` instead of `server.crt` (which I generated), it gives me the following error:

```
script/rails:24:in `initialize': nested asn1 error (OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError)
```

I've tried running various `openssl` commands to convert the certificate from one form to another, but all of them say my certificate is in the wrong form.

How do I figure out what format the certificate I was given is in?

Answer (score 2):

A certificate that starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and end with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` is in PEM format. What's in between is a base64-encoding (often split in lines of 64 characters) of the certificate in DER format.

The certificate itself follows an ASN.1 structure, which you don't need to handle manually generally.

You can't really compare sizes, since the size of the certificate will depend on the information it contains. Generally, using `openssl x509 -text -noout -in YOURFILENAME` should give you a human-readable representation of your certificate. (For non-PEM, use the additional `-inform ....` parameter.)

Often, `.cer` is for the binary DER format while `.pem` or `.crt` are for the PEM format. This is not always the case (and obviously not the case in your example).

Some PEM files may contain multiple certificates, often to represent a chain. A general convention (expected by a number of tools) is to make a certificate be followed by the certificate of its issuer (as you read them in order in the file, cert[n] was issued by cert[n+1]). (This is not always the case, especially when the multiple certs in the file are not intended to represent a chain.)

Your `server_interim.cer` is probably the chain of intermediate certificate, which you'll need to configure once you've fixed your problem with `server_cert.cer`.

I'd try `openssl x509 -text -noout -in server_cert.cer`. If it throws an error, your file has probably been corrupted somehow. I would check for spaces and possible issues with DOS/UNIX line endings. Otherwise, get back in touch with those who issued this certificate.

Comment: What issues with line endings would I be having? Currently, it's got DOS line endings, but if I change all of those to UNIX line endings

Comment: This sort of things: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/855454